# Define a set $I$ such that $\cup_{i\in I}{i} = \cup_{a\in A} (\cap_{\alpha\in a}{\alpha})$ (Garling vol. 1, ex. 1.2.5)

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Exercise 1.2.5 from DJH Garling's "A Course in Mathematical Analysis, vol. 1":

Define a set $I$ such that
$\cup_{i\in I}{i} = \cup_{a\in A}
(\cap_{\alpha\in a}{\alpha})$

We came up with the following solution. Will you please verify it.

$$ B = \cup_{a \in A} a $$

$$ C = \cup_{\alpha \in B} \alpha $$

$$I = \{ c \in \mathcal P(C) : \\
\exists a \in A:
\forall \alpha \in a: c \subseteq \alpha
\} $$

So that the set $B$ contains members of members of $A$, and $C$ contains members of members of members of $A$.

We filter (by the Axiom of Separation) into $I$ only the sets with elements belonging to all the elements of a particular member of the $A$ set.

Note:

As far as I understand, Garling introduced the union axiom in a very concise form:
there exists $\cup_ { a \in A } a$, i.e. we can construct a union of all the members of a particular set.

Then he hints onto the not-so-strict, but convient forms of it, i.e.

$\cup_{a\in A}
(\cap_{\alpha\in a}{\alpha})$ which denotes a union of intersections of all members of all memebers of $A$.

Comment: Note that $\bigcup_{a \in A} \big( \bigcap_{\alpha \in a} \alpha \big) = \bigcup_{a \in A} \big( \bigcap a \big) = \bigcup \{\bigcap a : a \in A\}$ and $\bigcup_{i \in I} i = \bigcup I$, so take $I := \{\bigcap a : a \in A\}$.

Comment: @azif00 Thank you, I think that your answer makes use of the Replacement Axiom in the very definition of $I$, whereas in the corresponding chapter of the book it is just mentioned, but not yet given. I think that if my answer/construction is correct, it would show that the Axiom of Replacement is not necessary to construct the said $I$ (I'm not sure whether it is important or not).